# Subject verb agreement question regarding "seem/seems"

Tags: verbs, subjects, agreement

Sentence: "Two weeks seems to be the virus's maximum incubation period."

What is the subject of the sentence? I can't figure out if it's the virus or the incubation period. Also, generally, when you have a plural noun, you're supposed to use "seem" (eg. Those cats seem upset) as opposed to "seems" when you have a singular noun (eg. That cat seems upset), but here, "seems" works alongside "two weeks". Why?

Thank you.

Comment: _Two weeks_ is indeed a plural noun phrase, but it refers to one continuous period of time, and that is what _the virus's maximum incubation period_ (a singular noun phrase) is. So the subject _two weeks_ should be considered and marked as singular. Would you say _Twenty-three years are his age_?

Comment: Thank you, John.

I have an additional question, if you don't mind.

"The virus's maximum incubation period is two weeks."

Would the subject of this sentence also be "two weeks"?

Comment: See also [Three inches of-snow is/are expected](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220838/three-inches-of-snow-is-are-expected), [thirty dollars is/are](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410041/thirty-dollars-is-are), [Are monetary values plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71266/are-monetary-values-plural), [singular or plural verb after units of measure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295341/singular-or-plural-verb-after-units-of-measure) ...

Comment: [Should we use IS or Are with 'Fifty meters (is, are) the length of this pool.' etc ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268716/when-we-can-use-is-or-are-with-those-sentences) ...

Comment: @BigV: In _The virus's maximum incubation period is two weeks,_ the subject is _The virus's maximum incubation period_. The subject comes first in English.